# How can I make my Bootstrap Date Picker work and is there an "official" Bootstrap 3 Date Picker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a web app built with Bootstrap 3 and jQuery.  I want to add a Date Picker.  I checked the official [Bootstrap 3 website here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/) but there is no date picker under components (unless I'm missing it?).

I googled and found this one ...

https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?#sandbox

I tried adding this date picker to my app using their code sample but it didn't work ... no date picker pops up when I click on the widget

```
<script>
    $('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
</script>

<div class="input-group date">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

I figured I'm missing some imports so I added these link/script lines ... but it still doesn't work ...

```
<!-- what I already had -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/juliet/resources/juliet.css">

<!-- new for the Date Picker widget -->
<link id="bsdp-css" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
```

QUESTION:

What links/script imports am I missing?  And (other than asking here) how does a programmer go about determining what lines are missing when you're trying to add 3rd party widgets?

ALSO ...

I noticed there are a few different widgets that are called "bootstrap-datepicker" ... I guess it's a generic name.

Is there one place where I can find the "official" Bootstrap 3 date picker?  Or do you pretty much have to download different ones to find one that works for you?

Thanks for any advice because I could really use some advice!

UPDATED WITH SOLUTION:

Thanks to a pointer from commenter @RK_oo7 I figured out what was happening.

Here's is my fully working example code ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Date Picker Test 3</title>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/juliet/resources/juliet.css">
    <link id="bsdp-css" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
</head>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
            autoclose : true,
            todayHighlight : true
        });

    });
</script>

<body>

    <div id="sandbox-container">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please put your date picker jquery code inside document ready state

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// your picker initialization here
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  This pointed me in the right direction to understand what's happening in the "script" section and how it is changing the "input" to make it behave as a date picker.  I'll add my fully working code to my posting shortly.